# Script Logitech

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

how do i include profile activation (9) in caps lock and how do i include rapidfire?
i have a logitech g pro keyboard too, i would just put the capslock to reduce a recoil that is big on the gun

```
local recoil_mode  -- possible values: false, 8, 7, 6
 local recoil_loops = {
       [8] = {
          {x=-1, y=2, delay=7},
          {x=1, y=2, delay=7},
          {x=-1, y=3, delay=8},
          {x=1, y=3, delay=5},
       },
       [7] = {
          {x=0, y=5, delay=5},
          {x=0, y=6, delay=7},
          {x=0, y=7, delay=6},
          {x=0, y=8, delay=4},
          {x=0, y=9, delay=6},
          {x=0, y=11, delay=5},
       },
       [6] = {
          {x=0, y=8, delay=50},
          {x=0, y=8, delay=50},
          {x=0, y=8, delay=50},
          {x=0, y=8, delay=50},
          {x=0, y=9, delay=50},
          {x=0, y=11, delay=50},
       },
    }
    
    function OnEvent(event, arg)
       if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
          OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_ACTIVATED")
          EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
       elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
          OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_DEACTIVATED")
          ReleaseMouseButton(1) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
       elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and recoil_loops[arg] then
          recoil_mode = recoil_mode ~= arg and arg
          OutputLogMessage("Recoil mode is now "..tostring(recoil_mode))
       elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil_mode then
          local loop = recoil_loops[recoil_mode]
          local j = 0
          repeat
             j = j % #loop + 1
             if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then  -- only when RMB pressed
                MoveMouseRelative(loop[j].x, loop[j].y)
             end
             Sleep(loop[j].delay)
          until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
       end
     end
```

Comment: this piece of code does not look like you've actually tried to implement what you're asking for. did you read the logitech API manal? you should be able to ask a more specific question if you have done any research. please read [ask]

Comment: `how do i include profile activation (9) in caps lock` - What do you mean?  `how do i include rapidfire?` - Which mouse button should act as rapidfire?

Comment: `to reduce a recoil that is big on the gun` - just include one more weapon in `recoil_loops` table for your new gun.

Comment: How do I point to the CAPSLOCk key on the keyboard?

Comment: button nine from rapidfire

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your English.  What means "point to the key"?  Please describe the behavior you want to achieve as a set of simple steps like the following: "when I press XXX, LGS simulates pressing YYY"

Comment: Do you want to simulate rapidfire when you press and hold mouse button 9?

Comment: Instead of clicking the mouse, I want to use the keys on the keyboard that is logitech !